# Using multiple elseif-statements to show different content in different categories

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, categories

I tried to use this:

```
    <?php if ( is_category(opiskelu) ) : ?>      

<div id="loop_meta_wrapper">
  <div class="container_16 clearfix">
    <div id="loop-meta-opiskelu" class="grid_16">
      <h1 class="loop-meta-title-opiskelu"><?php printf( __( 'Julkaisut kategoriassa "%s"', 'contango' ), '<span>' . ucwords( strtolower ( single_cat_title( '', false ) ) ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
      <div class="loop-meta-description-opiskelu"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
    </div> <!-- end #loop-meta -->
  </div> <!-- end .container_16 -->  </div>

<?php elseif ( is_category(lifestyle) ) : ?>      

<div id="loop_meta_wrapper">
  <div class="container_16 clearfix">
    <div id="loop-meta-lifestyle" class="grid_16">
      <h1 class="loop-meta-title-lifestyle"><?php printf( __( 'Julkaisut kategoriassa "%s"', 'contango' ), '<span>' . ucwords( strtolower ( single_cat_title( '', false ) ) ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
      <div class="loop-meta-description-lifestyle"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
    </div> <!-- end #loop-meta -->
  </div> <!-- end .container_16 -->  </div>

<?php elseif ( is_category(tietotekniikka-elektroniikka) ) : ?>      

<div id="loop_meta_wrapper">
  <div class="container_16 clearfix">
    <div id="loop-meta-tietotekniikka-elektroniikka" class="grid_16">
      <h1 class="loop-meta-title-tietotekniikka-elektroniikka"><?php printf( __( 'Julkaisut kategoriassa "%s"', 'contango' ), '<span>' . ucwords( strtolower ( single_cat_title( '', false ) ) ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
      <div class="loop-meta-description-tietotekniikka-elektroniikka"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
    </div> <!-- end #loop-meta -->
  </div> <!-- end .container_16 -->  </div>

<?php elseif ( is_category(media) ) : ?>      

<div id="loop_meta_wrapper">
  <div class="container_16 clearfix">
    <div id="loop-meta-media" class="grid_16">
      <h1 class="loop-meta-title-media"><?php printf( __( 'Julkaisut kategoriassa "%s"', 'contango' ), '<span>' . ucwords( strtolower ( single_cat_title( '', false ) ) ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
      <div class="loop-meta-description-media"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
    </div> <!-- end #loop-meta -->
  </div> <!-- end .container_16 -->  </div>

<?php elseif ( is_category(urheilu-liikunta) ) : ?>      

<div id="loop_meta_wrapper">
  <div class="container_16 clearfix">
    <div id="loop-meta-urheilu-liikunta" class="grid_16">
      <h1 class="loop-meta-title-urheilu-liikunta"><?php printf( __( 'Julkaisut kategoriassa "%s"', 'contango' ), '<span>' . ucwords( strtolower ( single_cat_title( '', false ) ) ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
      <div class="loop-meta-description-urheilu-liikunta"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
    </div> <!-- end #loop-meta -->
  </div> <!-- end .container_16 -->  </div>

<?php elseif ( is_category(hyvinvointi) ) : ?>      

<div id="loop_meta_wrapper">
  <div class="container_16 clearfix">
    <div id="loop-meta-hyvinvointi" class="grid_16">
      <h1 class="loop-meta-title-hyvinvointi"><?php printf( __( 'Julkaisut kategoriassa "%s"', 'contango' ), '<span>' . ucwords( strtolower ( single_cat_title( '', false ) ) ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
      <div class="loop-meta-description-hyvinvointi"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
    </div> <!-- end #loop-meta -->
  </div> <!-- end .container_16 -->  </div>
```

...... And so on (there is 25 different categories). Problem is that when I check the ids and classes' on category pages that are after category called "tietotekniikka-elektroniikka" (in example the page which shows category called "media"), this code above isn't working properly and the  ids and classes' are wrong. In example on "media" category page the divs look like this:

```
<div id="loop-meta-tietotekniikka-elektroniikka" class="grid_16">
      <h1 class="loop-meta-title-tietotekniikka-elektroniikka">Julkaisut kategoriassa "<span>Media</span>"</h1>
      <div class="loop-meta-description-tietotekniikka-elektroniikka"></div>
</div>
```

So I'm asking if someone would knows a solution for this. And could someone explain me why those elseif-statements stop working after the 3rd category?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're missing quotation marks around the text you're passing to is_category()

Comment: Umm. I feel bad for being this ignorant. IT WORKS NOW! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

For 25 categories, I would use the `switch` operator :
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php
That way the code will be better to read.

If you want to use `if`:
I would insert the `div` tag in the `php` tag.

If those two don't work - just re-code the thing. It may be a small error that you don't see.